# Git push rejected after cloning

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, commit

I cloned a repo from bitbucket using `git clone`. I made some changes and then `git commit`.
Now I'm trying to push but I get a `Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally`.

Now, I'm sure that remotely nothing changed between my `git clone` and my `git commit`.

Of course I can do a `git pull` but I'm scared to loose all changes I've committed.

How can I check what exactly is preventing my push?

Comment: if you do a git pull you will not loose all your changes.

Comment: The order of execution should be as such, 1.Git Commit, 2. Git Pull, 3. Git Push

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a git fetch first. That will download any remote changes, but not attempt a merge yet. 
Then you can look at the difference between your branch and the remote= cloned branch and decide what to do. A git pull would initiate a merge, btw, so you would not loose anything unknowingly.

Comment: `git diff master origin/master` would also show you a diff of the branches after the `git fetch`.